# убрать конкретную запись из контента

Tags: php

Как удрать(php) из

> э[metaslider id=57]вфывфывфывфывфывфывф ыфвфыв ывфы вф  sdasdasd

только

> [metaslider id=57]

при условие что 57 меняется.
Никак не могу понять как preg_replace работает

Comment: `preg_replace('/\[metaslider id=\d+\]/', '', ваша_строка)`

Answer (score 1):

> *Никак не могу понять как preg_replace работает*

*preg_replace()* производит замену совпавшей с шаблоном подстроки на значение, переданное во втором аргументе *(вроде бы всё очевидно описано в документации)*.

Если в случае успешного поиска нужно просто удалить элемент *(подстроку)*, то передавайте в *preg_replace()* вторым аргументом строку нулевой длины `''`, или `false`.

```
$str = 'э[metaslider id=57]вфывфывфывфывфывфывф ыфвфыв ывфы вф sdasdasd';

$str = preg_replace('~\[metaslider\sid=\d+]~', '', $str);

var_dump($str);
```

**[Результат](https://regex101.com/r/TQlqHI/1)**:

```
эвфывфывфывфывфывфывф ыфвфыв ывфы вф sdasdasd
```